# Where should I post a question about finding free-to-use OS icons?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question about where to find free-to-use OS desktop icons, and I am unsure what would be the correct Stack Exchange site to post it on.

On Software Recommendations it was OT. It's currently on Open Data ([Free or open source vintage desktop icons](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/11466/free-or-open-source-vintage-desktop-icons)) but likely to be closed soon.

Is there a Stack Exchange site for this kind of question? Perhaps Super User?

Comment: Not really suitable for most Stack Exchange - resource requests are generally off-topic, and where they are on topic, they need to be specific to the site topic. I don't believe there is a suitable site for what you want.